# How to Post Spinner Value in Volley

Tags: android, json, django-rest-framework, android-volley, android-spinner

I am using `Volley` to `POST` json object to Django Server.The object I need to post is in the form of

```
{
"name": "A",
"joined":true,
"description":"Info",
"status":"F",
}
```

My Spinner consist of this value to take status input from user

```
<array name="status">
        <item>Free</item>
        <item>Busy</item>
    </array>
```

If the spinner value selected is Free I need to post the status as F in my Json Object.How to read the spinner value and based on the position selected how to post this `JSON` object ?

Comment: So, you want to send only first character of spinner to server ?

Comment: `String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` will give selected text .

Comment: You will have to implement OnItemSelectedListener....

Comment: Question seems too broad And with that many tags . Consider asking a precise problem .

Comment: Yes I want to send Only First Character

Comment: @Satya, please check my answer below,

Comment: Use key value spinner adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If you use contains method it may false when string is Fire,Forest etc....word contains F

```
    if(spinner.getItemSelected.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Free")) { 
        // set "status" F to json
    }
    else {
        // set "status" B to json
    }
```

Comment: @Zaphod he has only two elements out of which only one element contains F in it.. check the question !! :) ty for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try thi

```
        JSONObject object= new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("name","A");
            object.put("joined",true);
            object.put("description","description");
            if(spinner.getItemSelected.toString().equals("Free")){
                object.put("status","F");
            }else {
                object.put("status","S");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnItemSelectedListener` for spinner then write down below code line.

do this :-

```
String item =spinner.getItemSelected.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to get selected text from spinner,

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();  // This will give you "FREE"
```

Code to get first character from string,

```
text = text.subString(0,1);  // This will return first character "F"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().charAt(0));

JSONObject object= new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("name","User Name");
        object.put("joined",true);
        object.put("description","User Description");
        object.put("status",text);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://....../kkk.php";
```

private void SubmitData()
{

```
    String item =spinner.getItemSelected.toString()

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {

                    final String result=response.toString().trim();



                    Log.d("response", "result : "+result); //when response come i will log it
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {

                    error.printStackTrace();
                    error.getMessage(); // when error come i will log it
                }
            }
    )
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("item", item);


            return params;
        }
    };
    Vconnection.getnInstance(this).addRequestQue(stringRequest); // vConnection i claas which used to connect volley


}
```

Vconnection class code....

```
public class Vconnection {

private static Vconnection nInstance;

private RequestQueue RQ;

private Context CTX;

private Vconnection(Context context)
{
    CTX=context;
    RQ=getRequestQue();
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQue()
{
    if(RQ==null)
    {
        RQ= Volley.newRequestQueue(CTX.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return RQ;
}
public static synchronized Vconnection getnInstance(Context context)
{
    if(nInstance==null)
    {
        nInstance=new Vconnection(context);
    }
    return nInstance;
}
public <T> void addRequestQue(Request<T> request)
{
    RQ.add(request);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if you use contains method it may false when string is `"Fire"`, `"Forest"` etc....

```
if(spinner.getItemSelected.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Free")) { 
    // set "status" F to json
}
else
    // set "status" B to json
```